# Water based concrete paint peeling and cracking. What to do?

Tags: painting, repainting

My indoor walls are concrete. I've painted one room with a water-based paint. Now 12 hours later it's cracking and peeling. I think it's because two thick layers were added without proper drying in-between.

For info, prior to painting only one layer of original paint was on the wall and a primer was applied first and properly dried, so the wall was pretty much clean before the real paint job started.

What do I do now? Do I have to scrape the entire wall prior to paining again, or is there some easier solution? I'm assuming painting it over again will only make it worse.

Comment: Any time paint is pealing adding a second coat will just make it worse. Cracking many times can be painted over.

Comment: Some parts have "alligator" cracking, but not down to the substrate. I think those are due to a second layer being applied before the first one was completely dry. So is it worth it trying to just prime and paint over that part?

Comment: Where is the paint separating?  Between which layers?

Comment: I couldn't tell. I ended up stripping/scraping almost the entire room and starting over.

Comment: I don't think water-based paint is a good choice to start with, it absorbs water and moisture and will deteriorate rather quickly. Clean up the residual paint, wait for the surface to dry out, then try acrylic/latex paint or oil-based paint.

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually cracked up off the surface ( of the primer ).

Wait untill it completely dries, take a stiff broom and remove the cracked paint. After this, take a orbital sander to any areas that are still raised.

If you can apply a thin coat of primer over those damaged areas and over the non damaged areas at the same time, then WAIT for all that to completely dry.

Then paint over that..*carefully* and let that dry.

Answer (score 0):

Not waiting between coats would be the cause, 6 to 8-hours is the usual wait for normal evenly rolled-on coats. But, with top-quality paints like Behr or Valspar I wait a day, because of rare lift-off issues. They take a month after that to cure & solidify. Another cause would be Cold, but you didn't indicate any such situation & if would need to be below 50-degrees.

You can strip it or you can skim-coat it with drywall Joint Compound to then start over with the primer & everything. Don't run your roller dry, just try to even everything out. Paint in floor to ceiling single strips & don't do a "Z", "N", "V" or "W" application pattern. Do 3 strips & then go back over those to smooth & even them out. Typically, only 1-coat is needed unless you're jumping to the other side of the color spectrum.

Comment: Why the recommendation to avoid those diagonals?

Comment: Those diagonals are very uneven in paint thickness or uniformity and, depending on the paint, can be very difficult to keep a wet edge. They "can" turn out okay, but many of the paint/primer combos today just don't go nearly as far and have a lot of trouble filling in whatever letter you've drawn...from what I've seen.